# Zend Framework 2 - Building a simple form with Validators

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-form, zend-framework2

I'm trying to build a VERY simple form and want to add the validation in the form itself. No need for million lines of code when adding it in the form just is about 3 lines.

Here are two of my fields:

```
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'username',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Name*',
            'required' => true,
        ),
        'filters' => array(
            array('StringTrim')
        ),
    ));
$this->add(array(
        'name' => 'email',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'text',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'E-Mail*',
            'required' => true,
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array('regex', true, array(
                'pattern'   => '/[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i',
                'messages'  =>  'Bitte eine gültige E-Mailadresse angeben'))
        ),
        'filters' => array(
            array('StringTrim')
        ),
    ));
```

The `$form->isValid()` ALWAYS returns true. Even if the field is empty. I have another field with a regex-validator, same thing... WTF, Zend?

My controller looks like this:

```
$form = new UserForm();
    $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineEntity($entityManager));

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $backenduser = new User();
        $form->bind($user);
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
             ....
        }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validation- and Filtering-Definitions aren't part of the Form itself. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html

Comment: i know. but i saw my code about a hundered times in the web... why doesn't it work? and i want to avoid this interface stuff because its way to much effort for such a small and not reused form!

Comment: so it's not possible to add a validator in the form def? like the say it eg here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7069700/1331671

Comment: That's ZF1, separate the Validator from the form! That's the way it is done in ZF2 ;)

Comment: just to be clear: writing or copy/pasting huge amounts of code instead of a one-liner is the new and better way to do it in ZF2? ;)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns It's the same line of code, just at another place.

Comment: well, thanks for your hint! I'm still in my Django-world where mostly the form stuff is derived from a data class or just set in a form - with one line ;) kind'a hard for me to get used to Zend...

Answer (score 0):

Try this, pass $_POST data.

```
 if($form->isValid($_POST)) {
     // success!
  } else {
     // failure!
  }
```