# issue in validation a form a in zend

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework

I am using zend form and try to validate a client side validation. My code is like:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
    'label' => 'Email:',
    'required' => true,
    'class' => 'span12',
    'attribs' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'pattern'=> "^[A-Za-z0-9._]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$"
    )
));

$this->setAttrib('id', 'lead_form_creation');
$this->addElement('text', 'name', array(
    'label' => 'Name:',
    'required' => true,
    'class' => 'span12',
    'attribs' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'pattern' => '[a-zA-Z]{4,}'
    )

));
$this->addElement('text', 'phone', array(
    'label' => 'Phone:',
    'required' => true,
    'class' => 'span12',
    'attribs' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'pattern' => '\d{4,}'
        )
    ));
```

By the above three fields I am able to create a form. Also my code is validating above three fields also. But whenever I am writing some valid email address and press tab then name field and phone number fields are showing red simultaneously. But user's perspective it should be only name field. Then if name is not validating and press tab, name field s well as phone field should be show error.
Please let me know whether anything I have to mention in the `attrbs` attribute or anywhere else?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Typo in your code (attribs should be attributes):

```
$this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
    'label' => 'Email:',
    'required' => true,
    'class' => 'span12',
    'attributes' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'pattern'=> "^[A-Za-z0-9._]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$"
    )
));

$this->setAttrib('id', 'lead_form_creation');
$this->addElement('text', 'name', array(
    'label' => 'Name:',
    'required' => true,
    'class' => 'span12',
    'attributes' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'pattern' => '[a-zA-Z]{4,}'
    )
));

$this->addElement('text', 'phone', array(
    'label' => 'Phone:',
    'required' => true,
    'class' => 'span12',
    'attributes' => array(
        'required' => true,
        'pattern' => '\d{4,}'
        )
  ));
```

Comment: But if I change attribs to attributes then it is not validating at all.

Comment: the attributes you are setting here are no real form validation but are HTML5 elements (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) so make sure you are using the right doctype and a browser that supports those. For server-side validation use, for example, regex (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068376/add-a-regex-validator-to-a-form-element-in-the-zend-framework)

Comment: if I use attributes, then it generates this: 
<input id="email" class="span12" type="text" attributes="1 ^[A-Za-z0-9._]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$" value="" name="email"> 
This id only for email and same thing is happening for other fields.

Comment: The pattern for your emailaddress validation is not correct but I would suggest using HTML5 email field type for this purpose (replace type 'text' with 'email') http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_email